# Expect - Spawn when double dashes are present

Tags: bash, scripting, escaping, tcl, expect

First to admit that i'm a scripting noob but basically i'm having trouble spawning an expect session when the command i'm trying to run has double dashes. Ie as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set command "mysqlimport -h mysql.someserver.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u root --fields-enclosed-by=\"|\" -p myDBHere --local /var/www/csvuploads/tablename "
spawn {*}$command
expect "password:"
send -- "mypassword\r"
```

I get an error saying:

```
mysqlimport: Error: 1083, Field separator argument is not what is expected; check the manual, when using table: INT_BRN_BRAND
```

Now i think I know what is happening. I think the double dash is getting picked up by the spawn and then the mysqlimport doesn't get it's field separator set.. It's the same reason you'd put a "--" after send. I believe this tells TCL or Expect that there are no more options for the given command.

**The real question**

So how does one spawn a process that has -- flags?

**Things I HAVE tried**

Adding a double dash after the spawn.
Escaping the dashes in the command text with \u002d
Use autoexpect to generate a script to do what i want.
Instead of spawning mysqlimport i tried spawning a new bash shell and "send --" the command to that. I got close but ran into a whole different set of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the `spawn` command has its own options, none of them are `--`. It only processes options until it encounters a non-option, and executables virtually never start their names with a `-`. Your official question is way off target; it's not the problem that you've got.

Your actual problem is almost certainly this: `--fields-enclosed-by=\"|\"`. Do you really want to end up with a multi-character sequence enclosing fields? I'm guessing not. Does `mysqlimport` support multi-character enclosure sequences? I'm guessing not (and would be surprised if it did). I'm also guessing that `--fields-enclosed-by=|` will be sufficient. Unlike the unix shell, Tcl commands that start subprocesses (including both `exec` and `spawn`, even though the latter is provided by an extension) don't interpret `|` as special unless it is an argument of its own (or as part of a very small list of other options, none of which apply here).

If changing the `$command` is impractical, the easiest way is to use the unix shell to interpret it by using a different way of invoking `spawn`:

```
spawn /bin/sh -c $command
```

Don't worry about starting an extra process. They're cheap by comparison with any database import.

Comment: Note that the problem itself is scrolled off the screen to the right by default…

Comment: Hi Donal, You're correct
mysqlimport -h mysql.someserver.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u root --fields-enclosed-by="|" -p myDBHere --local /var/www/csvuploads/tablename

in bash, worked fine AS DID
mysqlimport -h mysql.someserver.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u root --fields-enclosed-by=| -p myDBHere --local /var/www/csvuploads/tablename

Answer (score 1):

Try surrounding the double dashes with curly braces.  This tells TCL to pass them to the spawn command without expansion.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ls {--all} /tmp
interact
```

See http://jazimmer.com/tclbook/select/Html/2.5.html for more info.

Comment: This was useful and the correct answer to the question i actually asked...but it seems i was asking the wrong question. Thanks Ireeder!